# Remove accent / diacritic only on capital letters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

In JavaScript, I would like to remove accent and diacritic only on capital letters:

- À => A
- Î => I
- Ï => I
- Ô => O
- ...

I need to keep the lower case letters:

- à => à
- î => î
- ...

Is there a better way than testing each letter individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@newalvaro9 answer is ok, but it should be done the other way round:

```js
src = "Héllo Wórld ÀÈÌÒÙ"
dst = src
  .normalize("NFD")
  .replace(/([A-Z])[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "$1")
  .normalize("NFC")

console.log(src)
console.log(dst)
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove diacritics from capital letters using regex and normalize

```js
function removeAccentsFromCapitalLetters(text) {
  return text.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞ]/g, function(match) {
    return match.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
  });
}

const inputText = "Héllo Wórld ÀÈÌÒÙ";
console.log(removeAccentsFromCapitalLetters(inputText));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on certain characters that are included in the regex, but not sure how much it matters. e.g `Æ`, `Ð`, `Ø`, `Þ`. Not sure what some of these characters should be converted to anyways. If it is a problem OP could easily add an additional conditional for these specific characters. Overall very interesting solution!